# `that are hosted on a different domain` is embellish what in there?

Tags: meaning

When I read the doc of [CORS](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#cors):

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing is a mechanism for allowing clients to interact with APIs that are hosted on a different domain.

I want to know the `that are hosted on a different domain` is embellish the `clients` or the `APIs`. I am not sure about this, because in the scenario it should be the `clients`.

I am not sure about this.

Comment: I get that the cross-origin bit refers to the clients, but isn't it the APIs hosted on a domain? Different just means "not the same", so you can say "the client is on a different domain to the APIs" or you can say "the APIs are on a different domain to the clients. Both mean the same.

Comment: @JavaLatte Do you mean, there can understood as `clients hosted on different place` or `APIs hosted on different place`?

Comment: Perhaps you could ask this on a different stackexchange site about web development.

Comment: @BillyKerr I think this just is a grammar question.

Comment: @aircraft, yes perhaps, but aside from the grammar issue it would seem the OP thinks it is unclear/ambiguous. I don't know enough about the subject of web development to offer an opinion on that, hence my suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your sentence is that it doesn't say what the domain is different **to**. It's like saying

> Paris is in a different country.

... different to what? You need to add a **to** clause to make it clear.

> Paris is in a different country to Tokyo.

According to [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), CORS is a mechanism that allows a user agent (client) to access resources (APIs) hosted on a server that is in a different domain to the server that hosts the main web page.

This means that your sentence contains two omissions: first, the APIs are not hosted on a domain: they are hosted on a server in a domain. Second, the sentence  needs a **to** clause in order to convey any useful information at all.

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing is a mechanism for allowing clients to interact with APIs that are hosted on **a server in** a different domain **to the server that the main web page is hosted on**.